# Error in jdbc conection from Informix using Logstash

Tags: locale, informix, logstash-configuration

I am trying to get data from my Informix tables using Logstash, but there is a error about Locale, the conection refuses like that:

" Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Locale not supported."} "

I don't know if in my '.conf' archive there is a way to indicate the Locale to use in the conection, or that is something to put in some other config archive. I tried many diferent options with no results. Some info about Informix I have is CLIENT_LOCALE, DB_LOCALE and DBLANG but I don't know where to set up these values.
I'm stuck with that.
Any help is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash has a configuration file for inputs. You should have an input for jdbc.

```
jdbc {
  jdbc_driver_library => "ifxjdbc.jar"
  jdbc_driver_class => "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/mydb"
  jdbc_user => "informix"
  parameters => { "favorite_artist" => "Beethoven" }
  schedule => "* * * * *"
  statement => "SELECT * from songs where artist = :favorite_artist"
}
```

If you append to this connection string your locale variables like so

```
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/mydb:DB_LOCALE=en_us.utf8;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_us.utf8"
```

It should pass them through to the JDBC driver.  You will need to check what locale you need for your database to set in your driver URL.

Comment: Thanks Brian, Informix has these values: CLIENT_LOCALE=en_us.8859-1, DB_LOCALE=en_us.cp1252, DBLANG=en_us.cp1252
So my conection looks like that:
 
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/mydb:DB_LOCALE=en_us.cp1252;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_us.8859-1"

But still get same error: Unable to connect to database. "Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Locale not supported."}"

Comment: Exact connection is: jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:informix-sqli://host:port/mydb:informixserver=myinformixserver;DB_LOCALE=en_us.cp1252;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_us.8859-1"